# Acess iTunes backup while bypassing 2FA

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I have AppleID & pass.  My account.   2FA exists and can’t turn off (iPhone 8 plus, iOS 11.2).  Have device with authorized phone number in possession, so I can receive/use 2FA.  Problem is—even with latter, primary registered device is notified.  How can do it without Primary registered/authorized device being alerted?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (aka why you want to bypass 2FA)?

Comment: Basically: If it would be possible to bypass 2FA the protection offered by it would be pointless. So let's focus on the problem behind the stated problem.